# Indexing a data frame using slicing and lists

Tags: python

Is it possible to index a data frame using something like

```
df[[0:12, 14, 19], [0:4 , 6]]
```

where I want to get rows 0 - 11, 14, 19 and columns 0 - 4, 6. Using iloc I haven't been able to combine slicing along with specific row or column numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not allow indexing the dataframe like that, but you can create two lists. One list will have the indeces for the rows that you want and the other for the columns. Then, you can use the loc function to get your result.

The lists are created with the specifics in the example. List comprehension was used for the successive numbers and a list for the individual numbers outside of a range.

```
list_of_rows=[i for i in range(12)]+[14,19]
list_of_columns=[i for i in range(4)]+[6]
df1=df.loc[list_of_rows,list_of_columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

There may be a more formal way to use both slices and lists together, but its probably easiest to convert the slices into lists and combine them with  lists of individual columns/rows.

```
df.iloc[range(0,12) + [14, 19], range(0,5) + [6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can seperate the iloc comand in row 0-11 and column 0-4, for example

`data.iloc[0:14, 0:4]`

and then do the same for row 0-11 and column 6 and so on, afterwards you can combine the different ilocs